# What principles to use, in order to create field that will be read by OCR?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, ocr, pattern

I currently have an invoice, where some numbers are written by hand, and I would need to read them automatically.

My past experience is that people who write numbers will them write in so many different ways (overlapping with field name etc.) that it's really hard to isolate only digits.

Now I would like to redesign invoice, for example, to add field of some rectangular shape, that will be easily detectable (think easy to detect like a QR code is).

I'm not sure:

should I add some ordinary box, or are there any specific designs of fields/boxes/rectangles that would make finding the field and isolating everything in it (from image) simple and 99% correct?

Tech stack that would be used is:

- OpenCV
- Python
- HTML/CSS for creating the design of invoice, that would be exported to pdf for users to fill it with the needed information

Comment: If you are trying to recognise the characters themselves, then this question is not about "rectangular fields" but about Optical Character Recognition directly. Can you please edit your question so that it reflects exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

There's been forms like that forever: In Germany, the *Überweisung* (wire transfer) / *Verrechnungsscheck* (Cheque for accounting) have always been on things like this:

[image: Zahlschein.jpg]
[Link](https://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=2536737)

and as far as I can tell, that works pretty well with 1990's tech.

Note how the boxes are part of the "background" and are color-wise probably designed to simply disappear in a first processing step after scanning.

However, while that might be have been at a different level of initial investment, postal services find and read postal codes / ZIP numbers that are handwritten since at least the mid-nineties, so: Yeah, bummer that people aren't good OCR-compatible writers, but maybe your OCR just has to get better: Knowing that you're only looking for numbers will help a lot. Don't take an OpenCV example as a complete OCR solution. There's more to OCR than segmenting individual glyphs and trying to find the closest match to each one from an alphabet in isolation.

Comment: could you give me some hint for ` Don't take an OpenCV example ...` and `There's more to OCR than segmenting...` I would advise with google after your advice, but currently I know only for segmenting, binarization etc. I was thinking and looking into maybe frequency matching but didn't know where to go from there. Currently, I use things like morphology, pattern matching, convex hull/bounding boxes etc. So maybe I could really make my OCR better, the problem is I'm kind of new to the whole image processing thing so It could be that I don't see the solution.

Comment: You're thinking of OCR being *image processing* (e.g. filtering, binarization, segmentation) and then *glyph recognition* (pattern matching of sorts). What it really is is these two, but with a lot of surrounding logic: For example, if you can find a number that your algorithm is 100% sure is a `0`, then that shifts the likelihoods about how a `6` would look like written by the same person. Also, you would now compare a different number on the same form that you *think* might be a `0` with that known to be good `0` and get more confidence. You'd also not look at the digits in isolation –

Comment: you'd, for example, use knowledge of the fact that nobody writes amounts of money on invoices with more than two digits after the decimal point. If you find something that looks like `104.203€` on an invoice for a car repair, then you can be pretty sure that it's likely that you misdetected the `.` and this is most likely `1042.03€`. In "prose" OCR, you'd have dictionaries, you'd have markov models that have knowledge of which words are likely to appear in sequence, and so on. OCR is being "smarter" than just isolating digits and guessing them individually.

Comment: just to give you little more context, a goal is to isolate the number, then segment those numbers and feed them to Convolutional Neural Network that would tell me what number it is. That's why I need segmentation because CNN can predict only 10 classes of digits `[0,....,9] `, and the problem is really getting clean numbers to feed them to CNN, as it is sensitive to noise that may come with surroundings of the number filed.

Comment: so, as said: see the image of the form I used. But your CNN shouldn't have 10 classes, it should be giving you a number at the end, with multiple digits (what you want to solve is reading numbers, not digits). again: Higher order intelligence is necessary here, not just identifying isolated digits. You don't have a classifying problem (though classification might be helpful on the way to the solution), but a scalar problem: Just because CNN are *most popularly* used as classifiers doesn't mean that's what they must do: Many CNNs simply output  numbers. Yours should probably output cash amounts

Comment: I agree with you, I thought of classification each digit and outputting number using each digit, but for an approach to recognize numbers with CNN I'm not sure CNN can do it if it does not have a class per number and that does not make sense it undoable. What would be your approach to this kind of problem? What technique could I use, in combination or as only technique to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: you must mentally separate from the idea that CNN is for classification. It's not. It's a sequence of linear mappings and nonlinear activation functions. The last linear mapping can simply output a single number. It's what linear mappings do.

Comment: Do you know some good papers that implemented the solution in a similar way? I would like to get a better grasp for it, you are right in my mind CNN is for classification it seems that I did not understand the point behind it deep as I needed to.
I can't google anything without getting Keras/tensorflow hype implementations that are not helpful at all.

Comment: well, get any of the standard introduction paper to CNNs. Even if it just uses CNNs for image classification, just replace the last layer with a linear function that maps to a single number.

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow you here, how would you get CNN to throw out a good number, If I am getting this right, you would need to have data to cover all the numbers, CNN would have to get right? Or is there some other, to me unfamiliar way. Isn't the whole point of CNN to recognize some pattern and to guess what that pattern is. I'm not sure that I quite understand your intentions with `just replace the last layer with a linear function that maps to a single number`

Comment: My thinking is, again classification but classifying numbers this time, maybe I'm stuck with this idea of classification but how would you get CNN to guess a number, without training it with enough samples of each number you would like to recognize?

Comment: it needn't recognize all numbers between 0.00 and 100,000.00€ – it needs to do the right thing. You, yourself, a tremendously complex neural network, understand the number 5,614,588,989.73€ even though you've never been trained to see it. You learned to infer the rules on how numbers are built.

Comment: Well for that, would't I use 10 different classes and segment the number 120 into 1,2,3. If you think of another approach with your idea that last linear mapping will output some number like 123, please give some hint on how to do it.

Comment: No, you actually wouldn't! You'd look at a number that someone scribbled into a field and be like "this would actually be 020,99€ if I looked at the digits in isolation, but knowing that no one would write the leading 0, and that the 0 has a slight overshoot at the top, it's far more likely that this is 626,99€".

Comment: Ok, but how would I shape my training data set for CNN in that approach. My mind is stuck at one number (image of number) one label thing. Can't wrap my brain around the implementation for your suggestions, would you use CNN what would be the last layer, how would dataset be shaped, would you use anything else or are we just misunderstanding each other ...

Comment: You'd use scans of hand-scribbled numbers like "123.22€" , "626,99€", "20,40€" with the actual amount as labels for the training data. It would actually be pretty wise to feed the thing with pre-segmented images instead of the full thing.

Comment: The part where I use pre-segmented images, how would you use actual amount for segmented images as they are only digits I guess? And, I'm still stupid, and don't get how would CNN knew for something like "123.22" if I used segmented images as the input... It really bugs me.